# Communicate with Embedded JAR File

Tags: java, node.js, ipc

In Node.js, I am required to run a JAR file and therefore create a child process:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.spawn('.../java.exe', ['-jar', 'C:/test.jar']);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data.toString());
});
```

I try to use `child.stdin.write('test test');` to send data to the child process, but here's where I'm stuck – I have no idea how to get this data in the Java program.

I have tried the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Waiting for input");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String resp = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input got: " + resp);
}
```

... as well as initializing `DataInputStream(System.in)`, but alas to no avail. I see the line "Waiting for input" in Node.js, but it seems that I'm barking up the wrong tree by listening to `System.in`.

How can I get the input that is sent from Node.js with `child.stdin.write()` and `child.stdin.end()`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.in` is correct and the error was that I overlooked a very easily forgettable detail:

**`\n` must be added at the end of every passed message**, otherwise it doesn't go through. That's all there is to it.

---

I'd like to keep this question up in case someone else encounters the same problem. There is a lot of information about creating child process from a Java program, but not so much about creating a Java program that will act as child process itself.

Comment: This is probably what is meant in the [Node.js documentation for child processes](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html): "Note that some programs use line-buffered I/O internally. [...] it means data you send to the child process is not immediately consumed."